# What is the Fluent NHibernate Convention for value object list

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, conventions, automapping

I'm trying to figure out what the convention would be for a value object list, in this case an IList. Here a code fragment for my domain model:

```
public class RegionSetting : Entity {
    public virtual bool Required { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<string> Options { get; set; }
}
```

My automapping is set to:

```
public class RegionSettingMap : IAutoMappingOverride<RegionSetting> {
    public void Override(AutoMapping<RegionSetting> mapping) {
        mapping
            .HasMany(x => x.Options).Element("Options")
            .Table("RegionSettingOptions")
            .KeyColumn("RegionSettingId");
    }
}
```

I'd like to make the `.Table()` and `.KeyColumn()` overrides into a convention so that I don't have to do that everywhere I'm using `IList<string>`. I thought that I could create an `IHasManyConvention`, but it doesn't seem to affect this mapping. I set a breakpoint in my custom `HasManyConvention` class, but it doesn't break for the `Options` property. Could anyone tell me what convention I should be using to automate this override?

Answer (score 0):

Using an `IHasManyConvention` should've worked. Try an `IBagConvention`, see if that works. If not, there's a bug in there.